# PHP code not executing when run thru AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to execute data if the SMS OTP is equal to Session_oTp. So, that is working fine, I am able to verify the mobile OTP is verified or not. But when trying to execute some normal query it does not run.

```
case "verify_otp":
    $otp = $_POST['otp'];
    $orderId = $_POST['orderid'];
    $params = array("status" => "completed");
    $body = 'orders/'.$_POST['orderid'] ;
    // $woocommerce->put('orders/'.$orderId, $params);
    
    if ($otp == $_SESSION['session_otp'] && $orderId == $_SESSION['OrderID']) {
        // if ($otp == $_SESSION['session_otp']) {
        
        echo "$params";
        // $params = array("status" => "completed");
        // $woocommerce->put($body, $params);
        // print_r($_SESSION['OrderID']);
        unset($_SESSION['session_otp']);
        unset($_SESSION['OrderID']);
        echo json_encode(array("type"=>"success", "message"=>"Your mobile number is verified!"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("type"=>"error", "message"=>"Mobile number verification failed"));
    }
    break;
```

If I turn off the `$params` or `$woocommerce` query it works perfectly. Even if I try to echo a normal words, it's returning the error code.

My AJAX code is below:

```
$('form.otp-ver-form').on('submit', function(e){ 
    // $(document.body).on("submit", 'form.otp-ver-form', function() {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(".error").html("").hide();
    $(".success").html("").hide();
    var $form = $( this ), 
        url = $form.attr( 'action' ); 

    // var otpnumber = $form.find('input[name="otpnumber"]').val();
    var otpnumber = $form.siblings('.mobileOtp').val();
    var Order_ID = $form.siblings('.orderID').val();
    console.log(otpnumber);
    console.log(Order_ID);
     
    var input = {
        "otp" : otpnumber,
        "orderid" : Order_ID,
        "action" : "verify_otp"
    };
    if (otpnumber.length == 6 && otpnumber != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'controller.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',//specify data type
            data : input,
            success : function(response) {
                console.log(response.message);
                $("." + response.type).html(response.message)
                $("." + response.type).show();
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("ss");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".error").html('You have entered wrong OTP.')
        $(".error").show();
    }
});
```

Please let me know where is my fault or if I missing something.